# CSS transitions not working always with angular

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a simple CSS transition that I'm attaching to an element that at some point gets shown.

However it only works *sometimes*. Most of the times it the div gets shown in the last state (red directly if you read the CSS below).

In angular I'm setting a hash from a remote ajax call at init time. Then I regularly replace that hash with an updated version as I make more calls.

```
<div ng-show='hash["title"]'></div>

.box {
}

.box.ng-hide-remove, .product-fields-box.ng-hide-add {
    -webkit-transition: all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 5s;
    transition: all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 5s;
}

.box.ng-hide-remove {
    opacity: 0;
    background: yellow;
}

.product-fields-box.ng-hide-remove-active {
   background: red;
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle?

Comment: I have no idea how to.

Comment: @MB. http://jsfiddle.net